# Вывод в Python двух случайных значений из двух разных списков без кавычек

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

День добрый. Только начала изучать python, всю голову сломал над задачей: нужно взять рандомно по 1 значению из списка и вывести в 1 строку через '+' без кавычек. Эту операцию хочу повторить 3 раза с условием, что из 1 списка имена не могут повторяться, а из второго могут.

```
list1 = ['Миша', 'Вася', 'Петя', 'Антон', 'Лёша']
list2 = ['Наташа', 'Марина', 'Даша']
```

1. Пробовал имена задавать каждое имя функциями, тогда выводятся рандом без кавычек, но на разных строках
2. Пробовал работать со списками, получилось вывести в 1 строку, но с кавычками. Убираю кавычки через .join - не работает рандом

Помогите пожалуйста организовать вечеринку, а то уже 3 дня не могу распланировать :D

Answer (score 0):

а так устроит?

```
import random

list1 = ['Миша', 'Вася', 'Петя', 'Антон', 'Лёша']
list2 = ['Наташа', 'Марина', 'Даша']

for _ in range(3):
    print(f"{random.choice(list1)} + {random.choice(list2)}")
```

Comment: «из 1 списка имена не могут повторяться» (c) — shuffle ?

Comment: Спасибо, даже не думал что можно в 1 строку уложить.. А как можно добавить, чтобы значения из 1 списка не повторялись?

Comment: @dietbear13, тогда как предложил @OPTIMUS PRIME проще всего сделать - 1) перемешать список через команду `random.shiffle`, 2) затем в цикле просто выбирать по индексу от `0` до нужного вам значения

Comment: @Zhihar с перемешиванием списка логику понял, спасибо, почитал про него. За F-строки огромное спасибо, я в восторге вообще! Но не понял как по индексу выбрать значение из list1.. Подскажете? Все мои попытки выводят из 1 списка только по 1 букве, и те всё равно повторяются(

Comment: @dietbear13: `random.shuffle(list); for i in range(3): print(f"{list[i]}")` типа такого